# Passing variable to FetchRequestController - Swift

Tags: swift

I have defined a variable which I want to use in a Predicate inside FetchRequestController.

```
    var subuserID : String = "0"
    lazy var fecthResultsControllerDocList : NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<DocumentTypeList> in



    let fecthRequest : NSFetchRequest<DocumentTypeList> = DocumentTypeList.fetchRequest()

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dltPresent == %@", NSNumber(value: true))



    let loggedUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    let userId = loggedUser?.uid

    let predicateUser = NSPredicate(format: "dltUserID == %@", userId!)

    let predicateSubuser = NSPredicate.init(format: "dltSubuserID", self.subuserID)



    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicateUser, predicate, predicateSubuser])

    fecthRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate

    let sortDescript = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dltID", ascending: true)

    fecthRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescript]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fecthRequest, managedObjectContext: PersistenceService.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)



    controller.delegate = self

    return controller

}()
```

When I run this code, it crashes with the following reason:

```
   2018-03-22 13:11:38.479 AppName[5640:344901] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "dltSubuserID"'
```

Basically I want to predicate all the results using a variable passed by the previous ViewController. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator and the placeholder is missing (like in the preceding line)

```
let predicateSubuser = NSPredicate(format: "dltSubuserID == %@", self.subuserID)
```

---

Note:

The `dltPresent` predicate line can be reduced to

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dltPresent == TRUE")
```

Comment: Learning to code has taught me, most of the time it is better to review the code thoroughly rather than asking questions.